# Function no SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, funções, oracle

Como faço pra realizar esses `if` `else` no SQL

```
create or replace function inss(x real)
return number is
begin 
    if x <= 840.55 then 
        return ((7.65/100) * x);
    else if (x >= 840.56) and (x <= 1050.00) then 
        return ((8.65/100) * x);
    else if (x >= 1050.01) and (x <= 1400.91) then 
        return ((9/100) * x);
    else if (x >= 1400.92) and (x <= 2801.82) then 
        return ((11/100) * x);
    else 
        return 308.20;
    end if;
end;
```

Está dando esse erro:

> Errors: FUNCTION INSS Line/Col: 15/4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
> ";" when expecting one of the following:    if

Comment: Coloque `elsif` no lugar de `else if`

Comment: Deu certo, mas poderia me ensinar pq else if não funciona? Eu uso o 10g na faculdade e o professor não ensinou dessa maneira, seria por conta de atualizações?

Comment: Na construção que utilizou você precisará de um `end if;` para cada `if`, o que não é necessário na construção `elseif`.

Comment: Agora entendi, obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Tirado da própria [documentação do Oracle DB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#BABGEHAI)

```
DECLARE
  grade CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  grade := 'B';
  IF grade = 'A' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Excellent');
  ELSIF grade = 'B' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Very Good');
  ELSIF grade = 'C' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Good');
  ELSIF grade = 'D' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT. PUT_LINE('Fair');
  ELSIF grade = 'F' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Poor');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No such grade');
  END IF;
ENd;
```